# How to disable only SIMD auto-vectorization optimization in Visual Studio 2015 (for C++)?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, vectorization, simd

My question is simply how can I disable only the SIMD auto-vectorization optimization (keeping other optimizations of Release mode) in Visual Studio 2015 for:

1) the whole project being compiled;

2) for parts of the code.

In the first case, I would like to learn how to disable it for the whole project. For the second case, I would like to know whether it is also possible to do it for specific areas of the code, similarly to what is possible for all optimizations when using `#pragma optimize("", off)` and `#pragma optimize("", on)`.

The purpose of this is performance comparison of some manually optimized code against the compiler's automatic SIMD vectorization.

Comment: Turning off SSE support isn't sufficient?

Comment: You can't do that on x64 since all x64 has SSE2 as a minimum.

Comment: @Mysticial So you mean that I can do it only if I compile for x86?

Comment: @MSalters you mean by specifying `/arch:IA32`?

Comment: @blipblop Correct. Visual Studio does not let you disable SSE2 on x64 because all x64 processors have SSE2. So from their perspective, there is no point in adding the ability to disable SSE2 on x64 builds. Your particular use-case is very niche. An alternative is to use an older version of VS that doesn't have auto-vectorization. (VS2010-ish and earlier IIRC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual C++ auto-vectorizer is automatically enabled when building with `/O2` or `/Ox`.

To see what it is doing, build with `/Qvec-report:1` or `/Qvec-report:2`.

You can disable it for specific loops by using `#pragma loop(no_vector)`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx)

> There's no documented way to disable the auto-vectorizer globally while keeping standard optimizations enabled.

For more information, see this [blog series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/04/12/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-2012-overview/), this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/Getting-the-most-out-of-the-MSVC-compiler-AutoVectorizer), and the [Auto-Vectorization Cookbook](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/04/99/3007.Auto-Vectorizer-08-Cookbook.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where exactly did you find the quote above? I didn't find in any of the links you included (also not in the Cookbook). Maybe you missed a reference of interest?

Comment: It's not a quote as much as an aside. There's no documented compiler switch that just disables the auto-vectorizer.